# How to get particular string from a string in php

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$a=array("N","W","E","W");
$b=12.2134123N
```

i need to get that N only from $b .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
<?php
$b='12.2134123N';
echo substr($b,strlen($b)-1,1); // N
```

[`Source`](http://www.php.net/function.substr)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$b="12.2134123N"
echo substr($b, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can explode it as:

```
$b="12.2134123N";
$new_string = explode('3',$b);
echo $new_string[2];


//  output N
```